# Spring Data JPA fetching list always returns at least a single result

Tags: spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa, jpql, spring-projections

I've noticed a slight problem with how my API is working where I'm using Spring Data JPA.
My query looks something along the lines of:

`@Query("SELECT p.id AS id, COUNT(l) AS likes FROM Post p LEFT JOIN Like l ON l.post = p WHERE p.location.id = ?1")`

My actual query is bigger, this this contains everything necessary to explain what the issue is. This query will return a list, but assume the location does not exist, it should return null or an empty list, correct? Oh, how wrong you are, my sweet summer child!
This query will instead always return a list of at least one element, regardless of whether or not there are any posts linked to said location.

```
[{"id": null, "likes": 0}]
```

That is what the result looks like when serialized to JSON. I am not quite sure what to do about this little predicament, as I obviously don't want to return a list with faulty data, but needing to use processing to filter out duds also seems dumb and unnecessary.
Is there any way to prevent this that I've yet to find? If it is of any relevance, I am using projections currently for my responses.

What I've tried so far:

- Adding a not null condition for fields. Does not work, ignored by COUNT.
- Adding constraints to all fields @NotNull. Does not work, will still become null.
- For what it's worth, I've tried different kinds of joins, though anything but LEFT JOIN doesn't make much sense.

I haven't been able to find any other case which resembles this either, although it most likely exists, but is drowned out by everything else. I'm not quite sure what can be done in this regard, so I'm curious if it's just a quirk with the framework, or if there is an actual solution.

It might be possible to solve through native queries, but I would prefer not to use them.

Comment: That `COUNT(l)` is what is causing your troubles. If it doesn't find anything, it will count 0, as expected. One option is simply to get the size of the list in your backend.

Comment: @JettoMartínez The easier way of doing it would be to check if the first row has a null ID, which is what I'm leaning toward right now. This would be a solid solution as if the first entry has a null ID, there would be no following rows unless there is a malformed query, as ID is a primary key.
Your suggested solution would sadly not work either, as I also have a CASE in my actual query, though it suffers from the same issue as COUNT, so I didn't find it to be a big deal. The thing is that I would require three separate queries to get one set of results, which just feels inefficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the issue is inherently due to a COUNT and CASE keyword in my real query, resulting in there always being at least one row, and I can't find any method of doing this automatically, the solution I've used is the following:

```
List<Item> items = repository.customQuery(id);
if (0 < items.size() && null == items.get(0).getId()) {
  items.remove(0);
}
```

The first condition is arbitrary as I know there is always at least one entry, but is done just as a safety measure. A try-catch block would do the trick as well. In the case where you use a primitive int instead of Integer, you'd need to initialize the value in the constructor to something which would normally never be present in the database, such as -1.

If anyone knows of a better method, I'd love to know about it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm no SQL expert but I believe that a left join will give you this result if the ID does not exist.
Have you run the query in your DB? Doesn't it give you one row in your result set for IDs that do not exist?

I believe this is intended to say there is a 0 match.

You might want to validate your query before running it. Meaning checking that the location exists first.

Comment: The location exists, no issue there. As for the join, as I've mentioned, I tried different joins as well with no success. Generally you'd want to use a LEFT JOIN in cases where you can't guarantee the existence of any matches in the table (in this case object) you're joining to the query. INNER JOIN for the cases when you require it to exist in both. There are other types of joins as well, but these two are the most common I'd say.
The problem is that COUNT always returns 0 or higher, but that is simply never a problem even when I use SQL at work, so it seems like a framework thing.